# Error while filtering out records from grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We have a kendo react grid and we have the filters dropdown on each column, by which user can provider values and filter out the grid.
Those filters are working fine, only one column filter **providersCount** is breaking, column field datatype is int.

We are getting below error while filtering out:

**TypeError: (a || "").indexOf is not a function**

Grid code is shown below :

```
<Grid 
                        data={this.state.items}
                        sortable={{
                        allowUnsort: this.state.allowUnsort,
                        mode: this.state.multiple,
                        sortDir:this.state.sortDir
                    }}

                        sort={this.state.sort}
                        onSortChange={this.sortChange}
                        filterable={true}
                        filter={this.state.filter}
                        onFilterChange={this.filterChange}
                        onPageChange={this.pageChange}
                        total={this.state.total}
                        skip={this.state.skip}
                        pageSize={this.state.pageSize}
                        pageable={this.state.pageable}
                        scrollable={this.state.scrollable}
                        //style={{ height: '500px' }}
                    >
                        <Column field="networkName"  sortable={{
                        allowUnsort: this.state.allowUnsort,
                        mode: this.state.multiple ? 'multiple' : 'single',

                    }}


                    onSortChange={this.sortChange} title="Network Name" width="400px" cell={NetworkNameCell}  />
                        <Column field="networkGroups" title="Network Groups" width="250px" />
                        <Column field="networkType" title="Network Type" width="250px" />
                        <Column field="providersCount" title="Assigned Providers"  />
                        <Column field="locationsCount" title="Assigned Locations"  />
                        <Column cell={this.DeleteCommandCell} title="Action" sortable={false} filterable={false} />
                        <span class="k-icon my-refresh-icon-class"></span>
                    </Grid>
```

and we are filtering out the records by below function :

```
  filterNetworks = (filter) => {
        debugger
        const data = this.networks.slice();
        return filterBy(data, filter);
    }
```

Any idea what we are doing wrong here.

Comment: Where is the TypeError occurring? I do not see `indexOf` anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: it's coming in internal kendo js file, this is the line which throws error : var operatorsMap = {
> 15 |     contains: function (a, b) { return (a || "").indexOf(b) >= 0; },

Answer (score 2):

Set `filter="numeric"` for your column, this way the filter component will have the operators for number comparison and not string comparison. By default the [filter](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/api/GridColumnProps/#toc-filter) is text.

Answer (score 0):

This error could occur if the data or the filter passed to the filterBy function is not in the expected format. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dataquery/api/filterBy/